# Excel NPV/IRR - Populate a range from annual savings as input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To provide a valid input to the NPV and IRR functions, I'm trying to create a range of values of annual even returns for a given number of years. Although question is also valid for any similar excel function, my specific case is related with NPV and IRR.

My initial investment is 25000$ and I get 5000$ from that investment annually for 10 years. Interest rate is 10% for NPV and IRR.

Instead of providing these values like BEFORE I'm looking for a way similar to AFTER, if possible without any macros, only by using a few functions?

[image: Before: what works After: What i'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula is actually discounting a 25000 investment made in 1 years time, then receiving cashflow of $5000 a year from the end of year 2, year 3 .... year 11

You wanted
`=NPV(C1,C5:C14)-C4`
*=5777.84*

which as an annuity can be calculated directly with
`=-PV(10%,10,5000)-25000`
*=5777.84*

On your second formula
`=RATE(10,5000,-25000)`
*=15.1%*

Comment: although my values are a bit different, this is the right way to go. Just to conclude IRR is for uneven payments where RATE is for even payments. Thanks!